# Why isn't Storybook creating its default assets folder and files in the stories directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, storybook

I've installed Storybook into an existing React project:

`yarn add --dev sb`

Run `init`:

`yarn sb init`

Then attempted to launch Storybook:

`yarn storybook`

Things seem to start off fine, but after building a number of files:

```
[./node_modules/@storybook/core-server/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js] 97 bytes {vendors~main} [built]
[./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js] 2.95 KiB {vendors~main} [built]
    + 1683 hidden modules
```

I get an error like this:

```
ERROR in ./src/stories/Introduction.stories.mdx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/code-brackets.svg' in '/home/some-project/src/stories'
 @ ./src/stories/Introduction.stories.mdx 21:0-46 110:9-13
 @ ./src sync ^\.(?:(?:^|\/|(?:(?:(?!(?:^|\/)\.).)*?)\/)(?!\.)(?=.)[^/]*?\.stories\.mdx)$
 @ ./generated-stories-entry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-server/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js 
./node_modules/@storybook/core-server/node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/globals.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=false&noInfo=undefined ./storybook-init-framework-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/common/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/esm/frameworks/react/config.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/esm/client/preview/config-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/esm/preset/addArgs.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/dist/esm/preset/addParameter.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/dist/esm/preset/addDecorator.js-generated-config-entry.js ./.storybook/preview.js-generated-config-entry.js ./generated-stories-entry.js
```

Checking in the `stories` folder I can see that a number of files have been created including `Introduction.stories.mdx`, `Button.jsx`, `Button.stories.jsx`, `button.css`, and so on however there is no assets subfolder.

Later I receive the error:

```
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /home/some-project/package.json (relative path: ./src/stories/assets/code-brackets.svg)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I manually removed the imports and calls to the various SVG files referenced in `Introduction.stories.mdx` and Storybook launches successfully. I'd still like to know why Storybook is failing to create the files...especially since it could indicate other problems lurking below the surface I'd rather not be bitten by later.